# How can I create an executable linking the pybind11 module I created

Tags: c++, pybind11

The following works. It creates an executable and links to test_pybind11_module.

```
add_executable(test_pybind11 test_pybind11.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_pybind11 PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
pybind11_add_module(test_pybind11_module SHARED test_pybind11.cpp)
```

All good with the above. However, I want to link another executable(larger application) which resides in another folder in the project with test_pybind11_module.

I tried the below unsuccessfully - It fails to link to the methods defined in test_pybind11_module(test_pybind11.cpp). Note I cant really specify test_pybind11_module anywhere strangely and I do not want to have the source file(test_pybind11.cpp) to be part of the ${LARGE_APP_SOURCES} - that will be ugly.

```
add_executable( large_app ${LARGE_APP_SOURCES} )
target_link_libraries(large_app pybind11::embed pybind11::module ${LARGE_APP_LIBS} )
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get and in which step?

Comment: @kiner_shah It gives a link error when running make. So basically it cannot find(exact error: "undefined reference to") the functions in my wrapper class on the module(example constructor).

Comment: I think the Pybind module has an associated dynamic library. Try finding if there is a `.so` file corresponding to that module and if it exists, just add the path to that `.so` file like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/so` and then run make.

Comment: @kiner_shah it is not able to find my own classes(that contain pybind11 calls). I figured the issue - let me post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

To the benefit of anyone seeing later - I could solve this by explicitly creating a library(add_library) along with the pybind11 module for "test_pybind11_module".

Comment: Can you please post the modified configuration (like CMakeLists.txt) in the answer?